# SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, subquery

hello guys i was create a new system on database sql then i get this is error

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows 
=, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

here is a query

```
Declare @Weapon INT = (Select ItemID From SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Inventory WITH (Nolock)      Where CharID = @CharID 
AND Slot in (Select Slot From SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Inventory Where CharID = @CharID And Slot   Between '6' And '7'))

Declare @WeaponType3 Tinyint =
 (Select Typeid3 from SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefObjCommon where ID in 
 (Select RefItemID from SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Items where ID64=@Weapon))

Declare @WeaponType4 Tinyint =
(Select Typeid4 from SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefObjCommon where ID = 
(Select RefItemID from SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Items where ID64=@Weapon))

declare @RefWeapon int = (Select top 1 ID from SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefObjCommon WITH (Nolock) where 
                    Service = 1 AND
                    TypeID1=3 AND --- Weapon
                    TypeID2=1 AND
                    TypeID3=@WeaponType3 AND
                    TypeID4=@WeaponType4
                    Group by SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefObjCommon.ID,SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefObjCommon.reqlevel1
                    having  (MAX(ReqLevel1)<=(Select CurLevel from SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Char where charid = @CharID))
                    Order By ReqLevel1 Desc 
               )
if (@RefWeapon is not null) And (@Weapon is not null) And (@WeaponType3 is not null)     And (@WeaponType4 is not null)
begin
               Update SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Items set RefItemID= @refweapon where ID64=     @Weapon
end
```

i need fix for this is query

Comment: What part of this error message do you fail to understand?  You have several subqueries in your code example.  They are returning more than one row.  You could add `top 1` to the `select` (assuming you are using SQL Server, which seems likely based on the code).  But you have to decide what you want to do when there is more than one row and you want to assign the result to a variable.

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. Yes, subqueries cannot return more than one row if you use the simple comparison operators. If your subquery is to return more than one row, use IN or some such operator instead. Please clarify your question.

Comment: You could try using `MAX()` to make the row count 1

Comment: but i must select this is 2 itemid

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I'm not wrong, you are getting your error code here

```
declare @RefWeapon int = (Select top 1 ID from SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefObjCommon WITH (Nolock) where 
                    Service = 1 AND
                    TypeID1=3 AND --- Weapon
                    TypeID2=1 AND
                    TypeID3=@WeaponType3 AND
                    TypeID4=@WeaponType4
                    Group by SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefObjCommon.ID,SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._RefObjCommon.reqlevel1
                    having  (MAX(ReqLevel1)<=(Select CurLevel from SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Char where charid = @CharID))
                    Order By ReqLevel1 Desc 
               )
```

specially in this part

```
having  (MAX(ReqLevel1)<=(Select CurLevel from SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Char where charid = @CharID))
```

Why? Ok, `MAX(ReqLevel1)` is 1 value but `(Select CurLevel from SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Char where charid = @CharID)` will return a lot of values. So you cannot compare them

You may be should use

```
(Select TOP 1 CurLevel from SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Char where charid = @CharID)
```

Sorry for my bad english. Hope this help!

Comment: no brother it will return just 1 value the problem in @Weapon

Comment: why ? because i make select between and this will return 2 value but i must to get this 2 value first value 6 for weapons second value 7 for shield to make auto eqiump

Comment: `MAX(ReqLevel1)` Row Count is 1 and `(Select CurLevel from SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Char where charid = @CharID)` Row Count is how much? Both must have Row Count in 1 to be compared

Comment: So if you do a `(Select TOP 1 CurLevel from SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Char where charid = @CharID)`
it returns the same error?

Comment: yea it return the same error as i say to you problem in Weapon , Weapontype3 , Weapontype4

Comment: ok, you should run every subselect for each part, hardcoding the values when reference to another variable. You have to see wich subselect is returning more than 1 value. I can't see it without an example...

Comment: it's Declare Weapon INT = (Select ItemID From SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Inventory WITH (Nolock)      Where CharID = CharID 
AND Slot in (Select Slot From SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Inventory Where CharID = @CharID And Slot   Between '6' And '7'))
 return more than 1 value

Comment: Ok, so you must...
`Declare @Weapon INT = (Select TOP 1 ItemID From SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Inventory WITH (Nolock)      Where CharID = @CharID 
AND Slot in (Select Slot From SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._Inventory Where CharID = @CharID And Slot   Between '6' And '7'))`
It's great if you could solve your problem!

Comment: okey good but how sql will select the item id of slot 7 to update it :)

Comment: You will have to use a variable table for `@Weapon`. Which will be a table with all your ItemID (one column table). Then, for future refence, they will be by some SELECT query to `@Weapon` table

Comment: can't because itemid is a identity and hooked with id64 in _items table and items table hooked with refobjcommon refitemid on items and id on common

Comment: can you give me ur skype or yahoo to talk with you better

Answer (score 0):

here problem is that sub query is returning more than one row:
`SELECT TOP 1`, OR you can switch your = to IN and return multiple rows

example :

```
SELECT t.ParentId,t1.parentname as parentname, t.childid as childid, 
   (select TOP 1 table1.childid from table1 where table1 .childname=table2.childid) as childname
FROM table1 t
left JOIN table2 t1 ON t.ParentId = t1.childid
```

--->use your code here